# How do intelligent spherical creatures build houses?

Tags: creature-design, construction, alien-geometry

Imagine there is one intelligent species known as balli, they are as big as a basketball and can communicate to each other by emitting lights.

They do not have mouth as they can absorb energy directly from sunlight and they can roll around in all direction except they can't jump at all.

When 2 balli approached each other they will glow brightly and it will cause the surrounding temperatures to rise rapidly which can prove deadly, hence they will always practice social distancing.

One problem though they seems only capable of pushing object around so how can they construct any kind of houses?

BTW their rigid body is as hard as granite and they have been reported to produce 1 horsepower of thrust at peak and 0.25hp continously. Just a reminder, balli can't grip anything. Also balli are claustrophobic so make sure to leave at least 1 balli width around it that also apply to the ceiling height clearance as well.

Comment: Why do the balls want a house? What they might use the house for helps decide what sort of house, if any, they would need. Also how do they roll? They must either be able to deform or have internal moving parts or they would never move.

Comment: @LioElbammalf: they need shelter during rain and they have organs that impart momentum but don't worry about the anatomy ;p

Comment: Their anatomy is what we need to be able to move objects in order to build houses - exactly how it works is important for figuring out how they can manipulate the world around them. If you aren't bothered about the physics is there something ruling out telekenisis?

Comment: @LioElbammalf: you may imagine a mouse inside the sphere if that helps ;D

Comment: They don’t need food for energy and get hotter when they get near to each other? Sounds like these aliens are radioactive!!

Comment: @JoeBloggs: they can sort of like photosynthesis and they emit wide range of spectrum of light ;D

Comment: @usrt6760 You're handwaving an awful lot - why not just use telekenisis or something to handwave this too?

Comment: I've thought about this, but there's some things I'd like to know: How heavy are the balli? Can you say something about their texture? This would be useful in determining what kind of friction they they would exert, and how steep slopes they should be able to climb.

Comment: How does glowing brightly raise external temperature dangerously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without arms, they'd just have to burrow into something. They can probably dig similarly to a stuck tire, using abrasion to burrow into a hillside or the like. With only a family of one, they just need a roof.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to get a house built would be to hire someone of another race that is capable of building to build their homes, but this relies on there being another species that can build. Another option would be to steal nests from animals. While this does another species, this species is far more plausible compared to a distinct intelligent race. However, there is the problem that the balli have no control over the form of their homes